# How can I parse additional URLs extracted with xpath in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm generating a list of items based on an index page of sorts.  I have a start_url and a list of xpath rules to follow for each:

```
def parse(self,response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//tbody/tr')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = EvolutionmItem()
        item['title'] = site.xpath('td/div[not(contains(., "Sticky:") or contains(.,"ANNOUNCEMENT"))]/a[contains(@id,"thread_title")]/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = site.xpath('td[contains(@id,"threadtitle")]/div/a[contains(@href,"http://forums.evolutionm.net/sale-engine-drivetrain-power/")]/@href').extract()
        item['poster'] = site.xpath('td[contains(@id,"threadtitle")]/div[@class="smallfont"]/span/text()').extract()
        item['status'] = site.xpath('td[contains(@id,"threadtitle")]/div/span[contains(@class,"highlight")]').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

This code is error-free and extracts exactly what I need.  Now I'd like to visit each of the URLs and extract additional data from those URLs.

What's the best way to do this?  I can't seem to get the request.meta to work properly.

**EDIT**

Girish's solution was correct, but in order to get it to work, I had to make sure that my `item['url']` was not null:

```
for site in sites:
    item = EvolutionmItem()
    ...
    if item['url']:
        yield Request(item['url'][0],meta={'item':item},callback=self.thread_parse)
```

Comment: Use your ``items`` to trigger new requests and parse those similarly? Sorry what's the problem here?

Comment: I've been looking for an example and I've come up empty.  The Scrapy documentation's example doesn't seem to apply here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate a **Request** object with **url**, **meta** and **callback** parameters.

```
def parse(self,response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//tbody/tr')
    for site in sites:
        item = EvolutionmItem()
        item['title'] = site.xpath('td/div[not(contains(., "Sticky:") or contains(.,"ANNOUNCEMENT"))]/a[contains(@id,"thread_title")]/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = u''. join( site.xpath('td[contains(@id,"threadtitle")]/div/a[contains(@href,"http://forums.evolutionm.net/sale-engine-drivetrain-power/")]/@href').extract())
        item['poster'] = site.xpath('td[contains(@id,"threadtitle")]/div[@class="smallfont"]/span/text()').extract()
        item['status'] = site.xpath('td[contains(@id,"threadtitle")]/div/span[contains(@class,"highlight")]').extract()

    yield Request(url = item['url'], meta = {'item': item}, callback=self.parse_additional_info) 

def parse_additional_info(self, response):
    #extract additional info 
    yield item
```

Comment: This is very similar to one of my iterations actually and I received a similar error when attempting to pass `item['url']`:

**raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)**

I've tried json.dumps but that doesn't seem to yield the proper form either.  In addition, I noticed that I no longer have access to fields in my `item` -- is this because I need to change my approach entirely?

I'm new to python and scrapy -- just trying to figure it all out and the documentation is not helping me, unfortunately.

Comment: @Chad_C - Thar's because xpath.extract() returns a list and not a string. You need to convert item['url'] to a string or use item['url'][0]. Check the solution, I have modifying the solution.